# May have messed up my Mac Hard drive...afraid to reboot

Tags: macbook, disk-utility

I know PCs and hardware in general, but Mac is new to me.  I'm teaching my son about Rasberry Pis and told him to use my Mac to reformat an SD card and load the RPi OS onto the SD card.  Before he started I opened Disk Utility and showed him that the Macintosh HD was off limits...don't touch it in any way.  I'm pretty sure that in Disk Utility it showed directly under "Internal" ... so no folders at all ... just one drive, Macintosh HD. (but I'm uncertain about this)

When I came back later in the day that's when panic struck.  Now Disk Utility shows various folders that were not there before.  I have not shut down or rebooted since this happened.  He found the following YouTube video he used to try to load the SD card with the RPi OS:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xhZjpYQImck

I have gone through the video and there is really only one command that is run:

sudo dd bs=1m if=/Users/ericroberts/Desktop/2019-07-10-raspbian-buster-full.img of=/dev/rdisk2s1

I have not really researched it yet exactly what that's doing.  My first reaction was to post here to see if someone can talk me off the ledge that nothing too major has happened.

Now in Disk Utility I show the following hierarchy:

Internal

-> APPLE SSD SM0512G Media

---> Container Disk 1 . (APFS Container)

----- Macintosh HD

-> APPLE SSD Card Reader Media

----- disk2s1

I realized while writing this that when I eject the SD card that second set of folders go away...which makes sense.

Am I just remembering this wrong???  Were those folders always there for the HD?  I just don't remember seeing them before.  Maybe they were and I just didn't notice them.

When I click on the info button for Macintosh HD ... the one thing that makes me nervous is that in the list of attributes it shows as "Bootable = No" ...

Seems like the internal HD would be a bootable disk??

Thanks for any feedback.

ER

Answer (score 1):

I think it may just be the View in Disk Utility that's changed.

Launch Disk Utility… then from View menu, toggle between 'Show Only Volumes' & 'Show All Devices'.

For some reason, it always seems to say Bootable: No. I've no idea why.